# Add new permission on my Redmine plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I created a Redmine plugin and I want to add a new permission to it.
I followed the plugin Tutorial, but even if I'm logged in as admin with full rights I get this error then I try to access my plugin:

> 403 "You are not authorized to access this page."

What am I doing wrong ?

Here is my code:

**init.rb**

```
Redmine::Plugin.register :redmine_plugin do
      permission :my_permission, :redmine_plugin => :controller
end
```

**controller.rb**

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  unloadable

  before_filter :authorize

  def controller
     ...
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out, I changed `:authorize` to a new definition `:test`. 
I don't know if it's the good way but it works.

**controller.rb**

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  unloadable

  before_filter :test

  def test
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    if !User.current.allowed_to?(:my_permission, @project)
      render_404
    end
  end

  def controller
     ...
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. 
Seems `:authorize` work properly only if `@project` field defined. So, if project no matter, this will be enough:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_project, :authorize

  def index
    # some code
  end

  def find_project
    @project = Project.new
  end
end
```